# Photoshop: How to move selection after moving pixels?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

With the Marquee selection tool, is there a way to move the selection area after moving the pixels?

For instance, the `arrow keys` will move the selection, while `ctrl+arrow keys` move the selected pixels... but using the `arrow keys` after using `ctrl+arrow keys` to move, will continue to move the pixels to my consternation, when I really want to move the selection area without moving pixels.  Is there a way to fix this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround:

Have an empty layer. Select it in the Layers panel when you want to move the selection after moving selected pixels in the non-empty layer. Return to the non-empty layer when you want to continue moving pixels.

Answer (score 1):

Choose `Select > Transform Selection` from the menu to edit the selection (including position) *without* altering the pixels within the selection. You can then use the arrow keys to nudge only the selection.

For me, I created a custom shortcut (`Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts`) for this menu item.... allowing it's use to be expedited since I use it often.

Answer (score 0):

Experiment with `Main Menu → Select → Save Selection` and then after you do that other stuff, `Load Selection`.